# Why is my build take so long after its done?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been working on small some apps in android studio but when I go to compile it builds in a couple seconds then just waits for like a minuet before realizing its done. I've tried turning on offline mode and adding gradle preferences nothing seems to work.
It always says

```
31 actionable tasks: 31 up-to-date
```

then waits.

Could

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Be the issue?

Comment: I can make sure that Deprecation is not the issue here.

Comment: Which version of AS are you using? I have the same issue(mine is Arctic Fox 2020.3.1)

Comment: yeah it is 2020.3.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.